# Yii CGridView search with greater/less than operators

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to find a way to filter CGridView results with greater/less than operators in columns that contain integer values. 
Can I use the 'filter' parameter? Or do I need to create a new method in the model file?

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'event-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'name'=>'score_d_min',
            'header'=>'D',
            'value'=>'$data->score_d_min',
            'filter'=> , // not really sure what to put in here
        ),
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this goal by following the steps below:

**1- Add two property to your model**

```
public $compare; //compare value
public $compareOp; //compare operator, for example [>,<,>=,<=]
```

**2- Add above properties as safe into your validation rules**

```
array('compare,compareOp,...', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
```

**3- In your `GridView` add following column**

```
array(
        'name'=>'score_d_min',
        'header'=>'d',
        'value'=>'$data->score_d_min',
        'filter'=> CHtml::dropDownList('User[compareOp]', $model->compareOp,
        array('>'=>'>','<'=>'<','>='=>'>=','<='=>'<=','='=>'='),array('style'=>'width:50px;')) .
        CHtml::textField('User[compare]',$model->compare,array('style'=>'width:100px;'))
    ),
```

**4- Modify your model's `search()` method**

```
$criteria->compare('score_d_min', $this->compareOp .$this->compare);
```

Now, you have something like below (Picture looks different with yours, since I am testing it on a test User table):

[image]

At the picture, it compares the desired column like:

```
column >= 2
```

Result(As in my machine, I have 3 users with user ids in (1,2,3). So it only shows users with id 2,3):

[image]

Or:

[image]

**Notes:**

- I wrote code for `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=` and `=` operators
- Above code is just a working example. You may need to customize it.